# Security Error on IE11 when using Worker

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, web-worker

On some browsers my webworker( worker = new Worker( blobURL ); ) gives a security error. It doesn't happen on all computers with IE11, just a few. Is there a specific setting users need to turn off or on?

There isn't much feedback from the error either, it just says SecurityError and stops running my JavaScript code

Comment: Are you running it locally? If so, try running the file from localhost.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/801810/web-workers-from-blob-urls-in-ie-10-and-11

Comment: Just this [security error](http://i.imgur.com/8erRC3I.png)